# display data in input fields based from user input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple form that display name of food based from the first input field.

It is working, but I like to add another field for category(fruit, meat, vegetable).

How can I display the category of food in the last field

ex. 1 - Apple - Fruit

Thanks

**CODE**

```
var obj = {
  1:'Apple',
  2:'Chicken',
  3:'Carrots',
  4:'Mango',
  5:'Beef',
  6:'Squash'
}

$('#num').on('keyup',function() {
  var key = $(this).val(),
      result = obj[key],
      $category = $('#category')
  if (result != undefined) {
    $category.val(result);
  } else {
    $category.val('');
  }
})
```

**FIDDLE**

https://jsfiddle.net/gprkzs0s/1/

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: sorry sir I forgot. How can I display the category in the last fields.. like if I input 1 it will display apple and fruit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about an array of objects.

```js
function food(id, food, category) {
  var self = this;
  this.id = id;
  this.food = food;
  this.category = category;
};

function model() {
  var self = this;
  this.foods = [];
}

var mymodel = new model();

$(function() {
  mymodel.foods.push(new food(1, 'Apple', 'Fruit'));
  mymodel.foods.push(new food(2, 'Chicken', 'Meat'));
  mymodel.foods.push(new food(3, 'Carrots', 'Vegetable'));
  mymodel.foods.push(new food(4, 'Mango', 'Fruit'));
  mymodel.foods.push(new food(5, 'Beef', 'Meat'));
  mymodel.foods.push(new food(6, 'Squash', 'Vegetable'));

  $('#num').on('keyup change', function() {
    var key = $(this).val();
    $category = $('#category')
    $food = $('#food')
    $category.val('');
    $food.val('');
    $.each(mymodel.foods, function(index, item) {
      if (item.id == key) {
        $category.val(item.category);
        $food.val(item.food);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="num" class="form-control" name="number" placeholder="Enter Section Number">
<input type="text" id="category" class="form-control" name="category">
<input type="text" id="food" class="form-control" name="food">
```